# WordPress custom page issue

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Hi recently i copied code of a WordPress page (here:home) and pasted it into new page(home-demo)
[image: Initial home page to be copied]

and pasted this code exactly same in new page (here:home-demo)
[image: New home-demo page]

Now let me tell you what's happening as soon as i go to front end i see this situation in front of me
[image: This is home page]

And the copied page
[image: This is home-demo page]

so the content is not exact as home page . So i did some research and got this page in theme from where data is coming.
[image: The theme file]

You will see that number 1 is home.php it has coding of home page but i m not sure how this data coming in front end i have checked template no template is selected.

and number 2 home-demo.php i have copied the code from home.php to home-demo.php but i m still not sure how this data will get showed up in front end of home-demo because currently it is not so anyone there who can help me what to do and how.?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the slug name of the published page and make sure the custom page have same name as slug name.
2. Try flushing rewrite rules.

Comment: There is o slug name written.i think the issue is because i could not able get data from theme page i.e. home.php